# Не работает Comparator по нескольким полям

Tags: java, list, compare

В `FullComparator` не работает сортировка по нескольким полям (`channelName`,  `DateCreated` (в обратном порядке) и `Fingerprint`). Сортирует только по первому. Что делаю не так?

```
public class FullComparator implements Comparator<Capability> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Capability o1, Capability o2) {
        if (o1 != null && o2 != null) {

            if (o1.getChannelName() != null && o2.getChannelName() != null && !o1.getChannelName().equals(o2.getChannelName()))
                return o1.getChannelName().compareTo(o2.getChannelName());

            if (o1.getFingerprint() != null && o2.getFingerprint() != null && !o1.getFingerprint().equals(o2.getFingerprint()))
                return o1.getFingerprint().compareTo(o2.getFingerprint());

            if (o1.getDateCreated() != null && o2.getDateCreated() != null && !o2.getDateCreated().equals(o1.getDateCreated()))
                return o2.getDateCreated().compareTo(o1.getDateCreated());
        }
        if (o1 == null && o2 != null)
            return 1;
        if (o1 != null)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Capability implements Comparable<Capability> {
    private long id;
    private String channelName;
    private String fingerprint;
    private boolean isActive;
    private Date dateCreated;

    public Capability(long id, String channelName, String fingerprint, boolean isActive, Date dateCreated) {
    this.id = id;
    this.channelName = channelName;
    this.fingerprint = fingerprint;
    this.isActive = isActive;
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getChannelName() {
    return channelName;
}

public String getFingerprint() {
    return fingerprint;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return isActive;
}

public Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Capability{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", channelName='" + channelName + '\'' +
            ", fingerprint='" + fingerprint + '\'' +
            ", isActive=" + isActive +
            ", dateCreated=" + dateCreated +
            '}';
}
```

---

```
public class DemoComparator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

        Capability capability1 = new Capability(1001, "A", "R", true, sdf.parse("2015-12-15"));
        Capability capability2 = new Capability(1005, "D", "Z", false, sdf.parse("2010-12-15"));
        Capability capability3 = new Capability(900, null, "O", true, sdf.parse("2013-12-15"));
        Capability capability4 = new Capability(900, "B", "L", false, sdf.parse("2008-12-15"));

        ArrayList<Capability> capabilities = new ArrayList<>();
        capabilities.add(capability1);
        capabilities.add(capability2);
        capabilities.add(null);
        capabilities.add(capability4);

        System.out.println(capabilities);
        System.out.println();

        capabilities.sort(new FullComparator());
        System.out.println(capabilities);
    }
}
```

И разве метод может отсортировать все поля? Тогда получается нужно объектам полями меняться, чтобы одновременно в конечном результате все поля были в нужном порядке.

Comment: 1. Добавьте в вопрос код класс `Capability`. 2. Почему вы решили, что сортировка не работает? Если `channelName` совпадают, объекты вполне себе сортируются по `fingerprint`. Аналогично с `dateCreated` при совпадении значений первых двух полей.

Comment: @Regent Добавил. Разобрался. Благодарю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимо вы не до конца понимаете смысл сортировки по нескольким полям. Проще всего рассмотреть на примере учеников.
Ученик имеет имя и фамилию, а также год рождения. Существует следующий набор учеников:

- Иванов Сергей - 2000
- Иванов Артем - 2000
- Яковлев Павел - 2001
- Сидоров Руслан - 1999

В данной ситуации сортировка по нескольким полям (Фамилия, Имя, Год рождения -> по возрастанию) предполагает, что сначала ученики будут отсортированы по полю фамилия, затем **внутри групп отсортированных по фамилии** произойдет сортировка по имени, затем **внутри групп отсортированных по имени и фамилии** произойдет сортировка по году рождения. Таким образом на выходе получим следующий список:

- Иванов Артем - 2000
- Иванов Сергей - 2000
- Сидоров Руслан - 1999
- Яковлев Павел - 2001

Если так случится, что в список добавится еще один Иванов Сергей, но 1999 года рождения, то список отсортируется следующим образом:

- Иванов Артем - 2000
- Иванов Сергей - 1999
- Иванов Сергей - 2000
- Сидоров Руслан - 1999
- Яковлев Павел - 2001

---

Ваш код рабочий и вполне справляется с поставленной задачей, чтобы в этом убедиться, достаточно добавить еще один объект `Capability` в ваш список:

```
Capability capability5 = new Capability(900, "D", "L", false, sdf.parse("2008-12-15"));  
capabilities.add(capability5);
```

Данный объект после сортировки будет находиться после объекта с `channelName` **A**, но перед объектом с `fingerPrint` **Z**

---

И кстати, если используется java8, то вполне можно обойтись и без класса `FullComparator`:

```
Comparator<Capability> comp = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Capability::getChannelName).thenComparing(Capability::getFingerprint).thenComparing(Capability::getDateCreated, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
capabilities.sort(comp);
```

> Таким образом мы буквально пишем: Отсортируй список так, чтобы `null` элементы
>   оказались в конце, и сортируй сначала по `channelName`, потом по
>   `Fingerprint`, потом по `DateCreate` в обратном порядке.

Но будьте внимательны, если захотите добавить в лист `capability3`, который имеет вторым аргументом в конструкторе `null` (я так понимаю, это `channelName`), то нужно будет написать что-то вроде:

```
Comparator<Capability> comp = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Capability::getChannelName, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())).thenComparing(Capability::getFingerprint).thenComparing(Capability::getDateCreated, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
capabilities.sort(comp);
```

То есть все то же самое, но дополнительно написать, чтобы `null` значения в `channelName` при сортировке этого поля стояли в начале.

Comment: @Regent, код у автора рабочий, сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: @RomanDanilov Большое спасибо за такой подробный ответ. Разобрался.

Comment: @РусланЗарічний, успехов!